# Trying to integrate with Drive app, error occurs opening document

Tags: android, google-drive-api

am trying to integrate with the Drive App using the instructions here: https://developers.google.com/drive/integrate-android-ui.

I followed the instructions and now my app shows as an "open with (using google drive)" option when I select a file in the Drive app.  However, when I try to open with my app I get an error dialog that says:

"Oops... unable to open document.  Reason: internal error occured. please try again later"

Because the same file opens properly using other apps (the other apps aren't integrated with the Drive app, but they do open the file), I figure this might be because my app is not authorized properly.  My main concern is the applcaition id which the above link instructs me to add to my manifest xml.  It is not clear what this Id  is, but I assume it is the "client ID" from my OAuth2.0 client.  For me, this value looks something like(i changed some numbers/letters for privacy): 449637423441-e13a246wq7a0fuqgvremtjupk07vgf59.apps.googleusercontent.com

I have tried using this entire string as the ID in my manifest, using the portion prior to the first '.', and using the portion prior to the '-'; but with all 3 attempts I get the same error from the Drive app.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you enabled and configured the Drive SDK in the APIs Console for your project? The video embedded in the page you linked shows how to integrate an Android app with Drive, starting from the prerequisites and the project configuration.

Comment: yes, i created an api project and an OAuth2.0 client, the ID of which I am using in my application's manifest file.

Comment: Is the Drive SDK enabled in the Services tab? What about the Drive SDK tab?

Comment: yes, drive sdk is "on" in the services tab.  I haven't done anything with the drive sdk tab, i guess i need to complete the 'required' fields there?

Comment: thanks.  I'm unclear what i should use for the "Open URL" and unsure if I should check the box for "automticallty intiate OAuth2.0 flow"